# How can i test payment with sample card number on paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am getting this error while testing on sandbox "This card can't be used for your payment. Please add a different debit or credit card."

Answer (score 0):

try to login with 'facilitator' account in sandbox and then do the payment.

It worked in my case.

Thanks